# Any Logic Step Method

Tags: anylogic

I am building a dashboard for my System Dynamics model on Any Logic. I want to create a button that runs the model for 12 time units using getEngine().step() code. The method runs the model for only one time step of the simulation but I need 12 time units which is 1200 times the step. I was wondering if there any way to run the model for 12 time units and then pause it.

Also I want to start the model on a pause mode. I mean after clicking the Run button.

UPDATE: I found an answer to my second question. I created an event and set the following action to happen at time 12. getEngine().pause();

Answer (score 0):

create an event (from the agent palette)

Make the event happen after 12 time units (seconds, minutes or whatever you have)

Add this code to the event:

```
pauseSimulation();
```